# How to create looping(?) upload media button in PHP and store into MySQL, then display on separate page

Tags: php, html, mysql, media-queries, media

I am new to the community and I am trying my best. I jumped headfirst into some HTML and PHP programming, and have been working with MySQL.

Problem: Basically, I am trying to create an upload media button that "loops" essentially, allowing the user to upload as many images as they would like. This image will need to successfully insert into the database (MySQL) and be displayed on a separate page when the database is queried. I will break it down into steps with images to give everyone a visual!

1. Image number 1 shows the area where the 'upload image' will need to be, of course, this doesn't matter too much as it doesn't matter too much in terms of code, but this is what it looks like on the user side of things. I am looking for code that will allow multiple image uploads that will be sent to the database and correlated with InspectionID (the primary key) [here is the image of the user interface where the button will be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POajP.png) Image number 2 is the code for the form and the table. The media type is, of course, just a stand-in, but does not connect to the database. Likely due to many reasons, but, you know. [this is where the code I am requesting will go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI8vA.png)
2. The system will need to store images in the database and correlate to the InspectionID primary key. I have limited experience with MySQL so I am not too sure what the image type will need to be - here is a picture of my database so please let me know if I need to make any changes here. [current database table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glnkz.png)
3. Lastly, this is the page where the table is queried. It does not matter if image thumbnails are shown here or not, as long as they appear on this page where the table is queried, that will complete my system. [This is where the images need to be displayed or available for download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWiSa.png)

Overall, I am looking for information in three areas. Code to create a looping insert button that uploads images to the database, what I need to change in the database to accept the uploaded images/display them, and the code needed to display thumbnails of images/download the images within the table.

Thank you for your time and for reading this! I know I am new here so I am sure I have committed quite a few programming sins, but please be patient! I am new to programming as well, but I am eagerly trying to learn - thank you!

Comment: 2. You are using `blob` for your medias and I'm assuming that your gonna store medias as a `blob`. I suggest, change it to varchar and just store the file name of the uploaded image/media/file on your server. Then you can call it on your front end by just appending relative/absolute paths plus the returned stored file name

Comment: Don't post images of code. All relevant code must be pasted into the question itself. Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.) You should also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with focus on the "minimal" part. And only ask about one specific thing per question, or it will be too unfocused.

Answer (score 0):

1. DB it will be better to remove field `Media` and make one more table with images. It will have a structure like this: `ImgId`, `ImgPath`(the name of the file), `InspectionID`. Every file will have unique name, that will be given after downloading on server. We will save this name in table Media, that I described earlier. Also, we will relate every image to some inspection, so we need to save InspectionID as well.
2. HTML

```html
<form method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 
     <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple>
     <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'>

</form>
```

With this form you can upload multiple images.

3. PHP

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect(*some db connect*);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $countfiles = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
 for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
   $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]);
   $newfilename = microtime(true)*1000 . '.' . end($temp);
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],'upload/'.$newfilename);
   mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `Media`(`ImgPath`, `InspectionID`) VALUES ($newfilename, *You also need to make new row in the main table and write InspectionID to what the image relates to*)"); 
 }
} 
?>
```

So now you have uploaded few images to your server and you need to show them somewhere.

E.g. You display inspection with ID 6. You can easily select data from the main table, but images are saved in the table `Media`. The easiest way to get them is to write `SELECT * FROM Media WHERE InspectionID = 6`.

P.S 6 is used as an example, so you need to write your InspectionID, taken from DB.

Good Luck!